# Ant: Apply task: Adding an extra argument per input file in parallel="true" mode

Tags: java, ant

I have an `ant` build file in which:

```
<target name="foo"> 
    <apply executable="bar" parallel="true">         
        <fileset dir="." includes="*.xxx" /> 

        <srcfile prefix="--session " /> 
    </apply> 
</target>
```

This will call `bar` with a *single* argument of `--session a.xxx` for each file of the type `.xxx` in the current directory. How can I get `ant` to invoke `bar` with *two* arguments for each file of the type `.xxx`?

In the ideal situation `bar` would receive two arguments, `--session` and `a.xxx` for each file of the type `.xxx`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late but I hope anyone who faces this problem in the future can consider my solution and hopefully solve your problem.

For my example, I am trying to execute yuicompressor with multiple options operating on multiple input files:

```
<apply executable="java" parallel="true">
  <fileset dir="./js-ori">
    <include name="**/*.js" />
  </fileset>
  <arg line="-jar" />
  <arg path="yuicompressor.jar" />
  <arg line="--nomunge" />
  <arg line="--preserve-semi" />
  <srcfile />
  <arg line="-o" />
  <arg line="&apos;.js$:.min.js&apos;" />
</apply>
```

Since apply command with 'parallel="true"' will only apply the options on the first input file, the result is not what is intended. Instead of having ANT pass in the input files, pass in the input files manually using < arg line >.

```
<!-- Get the fileset as a string -->
<fileset id="myFileSet" dir=".">
  <include name="js/**/*.js" />
  <exclude name="js/lib/**" />
</fileset>
<property name="fileset" refid="myFileSet" />

<!-- Replace all ';' of the string of files from fileset to your intended options -->
<replaceStringWithRegExp string="${fileset}" 
                         searchPattern=";" 
                         replacementPattern=" --nomunge --preserve-semi " 
                         property="result"/>

<!-- We will disallow <apply> to take in input files by itself since we are already appending the input files manually. -->
<!-- Therefore we add 'addsourcefile="false"' -->
<apply executable="java" parallel="true" addsourcefile="false">
  <fileset dir="./js">
    <include name="**/*.js" />
    <exclude name="lib/**" />
  </fileset>
  <arg line="-jar" />
  <arg path="yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" />
  <arg line="-o" />
  <arg line="&apos;.js$:.min.js&apos;" />
  <arg line="${result}" /> <!-- pass in the string of options and file names -->
</apply>
```

This is my solution for executing yuicompressor once with multiple input files and options. I am unsure about other execution of .jar files but the solution should have a similar concept. If you find any part of the code that could be improved, please sound it out to me! Thank you!

Note: If you don't want to install ant-contrib for , you can use the replaceStringWithRegExp function created by Giorgio Ferrara in the link below.

[Reference](http://giorgio-ferrara.blogspot.sg/2010/09/apache-ant-how-to-search-and-replace.html)

Thanks Giorgio Ferrara for the replaceStringWithRegExp function!

Comment: The property definition and replaceStringWithRegexp are superfluous, use pathconvert instead : '<pathconvert property="result" refid="myFileSet"pathsep=" --nomunge --preserve-semi ">' or even with nested fileset '<pathconvert property="result" pathsep=" --nomunge --preserve-semi "><fileset ...></pathconververt>'

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra `<arg/>` tag to include `--session` as a separate argument:

```
<target name="foo"> 
  <apply executable="bar" parallel="false">         
    <fileset dir="." includes="*.xxx" />
    <arg value="--session" />
    <srcfile />
  </apply> 
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this will only add one --session, not one per file in parallel="true" mode

Comment: Yes you are right. According to the documentation for attribute `parallel`: "Run the command only once, appending all files as arguments. If false, command will be executed once for every file." you have to use `parallel="false"`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Still won't work since the goal of the question is to have the command only executed once. Thanks for time you put into the answer, though. Don't worry, I made this problem go away by doing it some other way.